# How to copy specific columns from one csv file to another csv file?

Tags: bash, csv

File1.csv:
[image]

File2.csv:

[image]

I want to replace the contents of `configSku,selectedSku,config_id` in File1.csv with the contents of `configSku,selectedSku,config_id`from File2.csv. The end result should look like this:

[image]

Here are the links to download the files so you can try it yourself:

1. File1.csv: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2o12qjzqlcgotxr/file1.csv?dl=0
2. File2.csv: https://www.dropbox.com/s/331lpqlvaaoljil/file2.csv?dl=0

Here's what I have tried but still failed:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=/tmp/file2.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,

[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
echo "no,my_account,form_token,fingerprint,configSku,selectedSku,config_id,address1,item_title" > /tmp/temp.csv
while read item_title configSku selectedSku config_id
do
    cat /tmp/file1.csv | 
    awk -F ',' -v item_title="$item_title" \
    -v configSku="$configSku" \
    -v selectedSku="$selectedSku" \
    -v config_id="$config_id" \
    -v OFS=',' 'NR>1{$5=configSku; $6=selectedSku; $7=config_id; $9=item_title; print}' >> /tmp/temp.csv
done < <(tail -n +2 "$INPUT")
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

How do I do this ?

Comment: Please post sample Input files in code tags rather than posting images or links.

Comment: Believe me if I do that it'll look messy

Comment: @Joe Certainly no more messy than those screenshots.

Comment: [mcve] We aren't interested in Tokens like NEWconfigSKu4 or the like, you could post "abc" as example, to keep it brief.

Comment: Have a look at split and join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, how about using:

```
paste -d, file1.csv file2.csv | awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$11,$12,$13,$8,$10}'
```

This is not as nearly as robust as the other answer, and assumes that `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` have the same number of lines and each line in one file corresponds to the same line on the other file. the output would look like this:

```
no,my_account,form_token,fingerprint,configSku,selectedSku,config_id,address1,item_title
1,account1,asdf234safd,sd4d5s6sa,NEWconfigSku1,NEWselectedSku1,NEWconfig_id1,myaddr1,Samsung Handsfree
2,account2,asdf234safd,sd4d5s6sa,NEWconfigSku2,NEWselectedSku2,NEWconfig_id2,myaddr2,Xiaomi Mi headset
3,account3,asdf234safd,sd4d5s6sa,NEWconfigSku3,NEWselectedSku3,NEWconfig_id3,myaddr3,Ear Headphones with Mic
4,account4,asdf234safd,sd4d5s6sa,NEWconfigSku4,NEWselectedSku4,NEWconfig_id4,myaddr4,Handsfree/Headset
```

The first part is using `paste` to put the files side-by-side, separated by comma, hence the `-d` option. Then, you end up with a combined file with 13 columns. The `awk` part first tells that the input and output field separators should be comma (`-F,`and `-v OFS=','`, respectively) and then prints the desired columns (columns `1-4` from first file, then columns `2-4` of the second file, which now correspond to columns `11-13` on the merged file.

Comment: I can't believe that actually worked, can you please explain what this line does `{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$11,$12,$13,$8,$10}` ?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer. Hope is clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your original script is that you are reading one file (`/tmp/file2.csv`) one line at a time, and for each line, your parse and print the whole other file (`/tmp/file1.csv`).

Here is an example how to merge two csv files in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Open both files in "reading mode"
exec 3<"$1"
exec 4<"$2"

# Read(/discard) the header line in both csv files
read -r -u 3
read -r -u 4

# Print the new header line
printf "your,own,header,line\n"

# Read both files one line at a time and print the merged result
while true; do
    IFS="," read -r -u 3 your own || break
    IFS="," read -r -u 4 header line
    printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$your" "$own" "$header" "$line"
done

exec 3<&-
exec 4<&-
```

Assuming you saved the script above in "merge_csv.sh", you can use it like this:

```
$ bash merge_csv.sh /tmp/file1.csv /tmp/file2.csv > /tmp/temp.csv
```

Be sure to modify the script to suit your needs (I did not use the headers you provided in your question).

If you are not familiar with the `exec` command, [the tldp documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html) and [the bash hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec) both have an entry about it. The man page for `read` should document the `-u` option well enough. Finally, the `VAR="something" command arg1 arg2` (used in the script for `IFS=',' read -u -r 3`) is a common construct in shell scripting. If you are not familiar with it, I believe [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126942) should provide enough information on what it does.

*Note*: if you want to do more complex processing of csv files I recommend using python and its [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package.